# GOG Galaxy and Ubisoft Connect: Connection lost

Tags: ubisoft-connect, gog, gog-galaxy

As title says, I can't connect and load my games. I have followed this [forum](https://www.gog.com/forum/general_beta_gog_galaxy_2.0/ubisoft_connect_connection_lost/page9) which said:

> Go to:
>
> %LOCALAPPDATA%\GOG.com\Galaxy\plugins\installed\uplay_afb5a69c-b2ee-4d58-b916-f4cd75d4999a\
>
> Open consts.py using Notepad or your preferred text editor
>
> Replace line 15 with CLUB_APPID = "Whatever you got from the Ubisoft login screen"
>
> Replace line 16 with: CLUB_GENOME_ID = "Whatever you got from the Ubisoft login screen"
>
> Save file.
>
> Make sure the numbers are in quotations as well.

But it is still not working. Here is proof that it should be working:

Does anyone has similar problem?
[image: proof]

Comment: Could you provide some information about your environment? Are you using some proxy? Generally, we don't have any info about your case, so it will be extremely difficult to find out some sensible and conscious solution. Good point is that the problem exists on two different game launchers. Please, provide some more data like that :)

Comment: @TravelerVihaan well I am "typical user " which means install gog from official website, click on connect platfroms and Ubisoft connect is not working. So I tried to find solution and I found forum on gog where community try to figure it out.  I followed steps above and nothing happend

Comment: Did you set the edited file to 'read-only' (after editing)? That might work. Also: do you have a Ubisoft account, and did you sign in (just to make sure :)?

Comment: yep I set file to "read only" after editing. also I  downloaded ubisoft connect to make sure it is working.also I tried different CLUB_APPID and CLUB_GENOME_ID @Joachim

Answer (score 1):

I went over to check mine and apparently i had the same issue which I solved following these steps:

1. Open **consts.py** and **remove the values between ""** for both **CLUB_APPID** and **CLUB_GENOME_ID**
2. Restart GOG Client
3. From Settings **Disconnect** the **Uplay** integration
4. Go to **[www.ubisoft.com](http://www.ubisoft.com)** and try to login. You will see a popup. Copy **CLUB_APPID** and **CLUB_GENOME_ID** back into **consts.py**. **Save** the file.
5. Restart GOG Client.

Connection should be working. I restarted the client a few times and it seem to be persistent !

Comment: CLUB_APPID and CLUB_GENOME_ID should be same for everyone? or am I wrong? 

Btw thanks for response, I am gonna check it out

Comment: Mine are matching the endings for the ones on the screenshot so probably they are the same !

Comment: btw how can you in step 3 disconnect Uplay integration if you arent connected?

Comment: you should be ok with the rest of the steps. i added that because i only had the reconnect option that was failing there so i had to force it to show me the disconnect option first.